# Dealing with duplicates in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql

If I'm writing data that I web-scrape into SQL tables from Python via SQLAlchemy and if I have a large data set that I am dealing with and would like to update these tables with new information on a daily basis, how can I deal with duplicated data? It seems that the update unfortunately doesn't overwrite the data that was previously in the table, but instead just adds to the existing data in the table. Should I delete all the data from the SQL tables and then do the update or is there a way to overwrite the data in the tables?

**Edit**:

The tables are as follows. I manually write data into `yc_data_source` and `yc`. I write data into `yc_node_hist` and `yc_param_hist` by using dataframes which have the data `curve_date`, `tenor_years` and `yield_pct` along with `param_1` through to `param_5`. I have an update function which inserts new data into the dataframes depending on if new data is available on the sites from which I am scraping from and then insert this data into these tables.

```
create table yc_data_source
(
    id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    name varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
    loader_class varchar(32) NOT NULL
)

create table yc
(
    id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    ccy char(3) NOT NULL, 
    fk_yc_data_source bigint NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES yc_data_source(id),
    primary_fl bit NOT NULL,
    party_id varchar(1024),
    typeofbond char(3) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    parametrized_fl bit NOT NULL,
    model varchar(128)
)

create table yc_update
(
    id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    fk_yc bigint NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES yc(id),
    update_time datetime NOT NULL,
    curve_date_start date,
    curve_date_end date,
    success bit NOT NULL,
    message varchar(4096)
)

create table yc_node_hist
(
    id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    fk_yc_update bigint NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES yc_update(id),
    curve_date date NOT NULL,
    tenor_years float NOT NULL,
    yield_pct float NOT NULL
)

create table yc_param_hist
(
    id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    fk_yc_update bigint NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES yc_update(id),
    curve_date date NOT NULL,
    param_1 float NOT NULL,
    param_2 float,
    param_3 float,
    param_4 float,
    param_5 float,
)
```

Comment: I think your question is too broad and it's rather related to relative databases in general (not SQLAlchemy specific). There's many possible solutions and all depends on data structure (which you described very roughly). If you provided more information, maybe I (or somebody else) could help.

Comment: @Tupteq I've added more detail to the question. Please let me know if more information is necessary.

Comment: What do you do to uniquely identify data such that it is not a duplicate?  If you can programmatically codify that into a function, the use that to find the dupes between the data frame to be uploaded and the existing data.  Then don't upload the dupes.